# Discrete math(ternary string)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many ternary strings of length 10 that contain exactly 2 1s and 3 2s.
Since it must contain exactly 2 1s and 3 2s the other 5 spaces must be 0s.But how many ways can  we arrange this?

Comment: Wait I think it's 5!×3!×2!?Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Answer : $\binom{2}{10} \times \binom{3}{8}=\dfrac{10!}{2!(10-8)!}\dfrac{8!}{3!(8-3)!}=\dfrac{10!}{2!3!5!}$

(using classical formula $\binom{n}{p}=\dfrac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$.)

You first choose the 2 places (among 10)  where you place the 1s, then, for each of these choices,  you can select the 3 places where you will place a 2 (in each case among the remaining 8 places). No more choices for the other places where the zeros will be placed.

Remark: The last expression in (1) could be obtained directly as a "trinomial coefficient".

Comment: Why is it 10!/(2!3!5!)?What's the 10! for?

Comment: I will give the intermediate computation in my answer.